# How can I create a graphics drawing of a Core Data entity?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, rectangles

I'm trying to create a graphic representation of a core data entity.  I have a custom view (subclass of NSView) where the drawing will happen.  My entity has name, width, and height attributes.  When I click the "add" button to add a new model object, I also want to create a simple rectangle for each model object created drawn within the custom view.  I have my table views set up for the data, and they are working great.
Do I place an array controller, and an object instance in the custom view nib file, and somehow use bindings?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do this by implementing the [`drawRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCDGJHF) function in your custom NSView. You should somehow inform your NSView of entity changes - both in the properties of your entities, as well as when they are added or deleted - and have your view redraw itself when these changes occur.

Inside the `drawRect:` function, you can iterate over your entities, getting the height and width attributes and using the [Cocoa Drawing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290) functions to translate those entities into visible rectangles within your view.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tim.  I'm going to try that today.